# DOCUMENT_ROOT opening file instead of giving absolute URL in echo

Tags: php, path, global-variables

I am working on a navbar, and this is how my directory structure is:

```
-- localhost
  |- navbar.php
  |- file1.php
  |- file2.php
  |-- AttendanceFolder
    |- file3.php
```

In the navbar, I have assigned URLs like this:

```
<a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/file1.php">File1</a>

<?php
   if(condition) 
   { 
      echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file2.php'>File2</a>";
   }
?>

<a href="<?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?>/AttendanceFolder/file3.php">File3</a>
```

My problem is that for **file1** and **file3**, it shows the URLs correctly in all pages like `localhost/file1.php` and `localhost/AttendanceFolder/file3.php`, but for **file2.php**, it is giving me the absolute directory path of Windows Explorer and reading it as a file like this:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/file2.php
```

and naturally I cannot access this page as it is not being processed by the server. Is there any way to fix this problem? I tried looking it up but cannot find a similar problem with a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the `echo` command, nothing gets written into the output. So for `file1.php` and `file2.php`, it's ignoring `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. Your code is equivalent to:

```
<a href="/file1.php">File1</a>

<?php
   if(condition) 
   { 
      echo "<a href='" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/file2.php'>File2</a>";
   }
?>

<a href="/AttendanceFolder/file3.php">File3</a>
```

The value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is `C:/xampp/htdocs`, so that gets put into the `file2.php` URL.

It's practically never appropriate to use `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in URLs. It's an absolute pathname local to the server, but URLs used by clients need to be the pathname relative to the document root, not including it. This variable is only useful when accessing files locally from PHP.

So change `file2.php` to just:

```
<?php
   if(condition) 
   { 
      echo "<a href='/file2.php'>File2</a>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying DOCUMENT_ROOT. How would you suggest I make my navbar.php dynamic so I could include it in every page; instead of specifying absolute path in each file in each folder (I have a couple of folders with a couple of files in each of them).

Comment: Why can't you use absolute paths in the navbar? The locations of the pages you're linking to don't move depending on where you're coming from.

Comment: So / was the problem. I was trying to do ***<a href='file2.php'>File2</a>*** in all my URLs, instead of ***/file2.php***, that's why I ended up using $_SERVER variable in the first place because from ***AttendanceFolder***  files, it could not redirect back. Thank you for the help!